# UISearchBar background image working weirdly

Tags: xcode, ios8, uisearchbar

I'm looking to do a simple one colour search bar like this:

[image]

I've succeeded in doing this in my view controller by setting this image as a background image:

[image]

and with this code:

```
 [self.searchBar setTranslucent:NO];
 [self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However when I click on the search bar and it goes into the searchdisplaycontroller, it looks like this:

[image]

There's a white section there that I can't get rid off. I've tried doing this:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm a bit puzzled as to why they act differently since they're both uisearchbars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting borderColor and borderWidth for UISearchBar layer it will fix your color change
remember that you have to keep in mind that for ios7 and later view position is different so use as i mentioned below. also i have subclass for UISearchBar, if u want u too create one or replace self by your serachBar

```
- (void)setup
{
    self.placeholder       = @"Search Products";

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        UIView *topView = self.subviews[0];
        [self searchBarCustomization:topView.subviews];
    } else {
        self.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
        [self searchBarCustomization:self.subviews];
    }
}

- (void)searchBarCustomization:(NSArray *)subViews
{
     for (UIView *subView in subViews) {
         if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
             [self customSearchBarField:subView];
         }
         if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
             [self customSearchCancelButton:subView];
        }
     }
}

- (void)customSearchBarField:(id)searchBarField
{
    UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *) searchBarField;
    if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        searchField.background = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        searchField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    }
}
```